# magento htaccess allow access specific folder

Tags: magento-1.9, htaccess, permissions

I want to access a folder in root directory in `Magento` like `example.com/foldername` but i got a blank page.

**So my question:**

**how i can allow access specific folder in root directory in `Magento` using `htaccess` ?**

Comment: why do you assume this is an htacces issue? fo you have any contents in that folder?

Answer (score 0):

Create a index.php file and put this code :

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
     <?php echo 'Hi There'; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

And then access it `example.com/foldername`

If above not worked then create a .htaccess file and add the following code in that file:

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Magento 2.4.x please keep a folder inside the pub directory and provide read-write permission as below.

_
Pub/foldername

Permission -

> Chmod -R 777 pub/foldername

Thanks